# Is there any difference when using map or for loop inside a list in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, for-loop, dart, iterator

I wasn't able to find an answer to this. Hope any of you can explain if there is any difference beyond that one of them looks prettier.

Let's say I have a list of Strings (just an example, any list use case fits)

```
final strings = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'];
```

And I want to render those strings in some Text widgets.

Doing it with a for loop, like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    for(final string in strings)
      Text(string),
  ],
);
```

Or doing it with map, like this:

```
Column(
    children: strings.map((String string) => Text(string)).toList()
);
```

Is there any difference in performance or something else?

Comment: The short answer is yes. Technically map is a tad slower but in reality there is no chance your application will scale to a point where it is noticeable at all. Flutter will choke long before you reach that point. I always prefer `map` because it preserves functional composition and easier to read imo

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a significant difference in the performance.

[image: comparison chart between for loop, while loop and map with different version]

For more details see [here](https://itnext.io/comparing-darts-loops-which-is-the-fastest-731a03ad42a2)

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case it won't change the end result.

However some functions on list, `map` included return a lazy Iterator. Which means that any computation that happens before the `toList()` will be made only on the necessary items.

In other words if you have a list of 100 elements and call `myList.map(mappingFn).take(5).toList()` the mapping function will be called only 5 times.

For example:

```
void main() {
  // mappingFn will be called 2 times
  [1,2,3,4,5].map(mappingFn).take(2).toList();
}

String mappingFn(int n) {
  print('called $n');
  return n.toString();
}
```